# How to calculate critical value for a sign test

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I would like to use the sign test on some data in R, I know how to do this however how would i calculate the critical value of the data? If I don't know het distribution of the data what command should I use to get the critical value ? Do I use qnorm(alfa/2) or do I use qt or can't I calculate the critical value if I don't know the distribution?

Comment: Can you say specifically what sign test: One or two-sided? Is $H_0$ specified in terms of population median $\eta?$ Are data continuous of discrete? Do you have particular data in mind? Are there enough observations to use a normal aprx? // If norm aprx is OK, then you can use `qnorm` to get p-value, not critical value. You might use `qnorm` to get critical value.  Student's t distribution has nothing to do with sign tests, so you wouldn't use `qt` for anything. // If you can state $H_0, H_a$ and give sample data, maybe one of us can show details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment:* Here is a quick example with output from Minitab.
If this is not the kind of data, $H_0,$ and $H_a$ you have in mind,
then please be clear about what changes need to be made in order
to help with the sign test you have in mind.

```
Data Display 

x
     7    16    23    28    55    70    87    92   129   160

Sign Test for Median 

Sign test of median =  20.00 versus > 20.00

     n  Below  Equal  Above       P  Median
x   10      2      0      8  0.0547   62.50
```

In R, under $H_0,$ the exact binomial probability of 8 or more 'Above', $P(A \ge 8) = 1 - P(A \le 7),$
is the P-value:

```
1 - pbinom(7, 10, .5)
[1] 0.0546875
```

Using a normal approximation to $\mathsf{Binom}(10, .5),$ you can get the critical value $7.6$ for a "5% level" test:

```
qnorm(.95, 5, sqrt(10/4))
[1] 7.600742
```

The quotes are because it is not possible to have a test *exactly* at the 5% level using the discrete binomial distribution. This
difficulty is "swept under the rug" using a normal approximation.

Comment: [This page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253984/sign-test-for-hypothesized-median?rq=1), under Related at the right may be helpful.